# Linux Shutdown with dbus-send

Tags: linux, command-line, shutdown, dbus

I am writing a Java app to shutdown my Linux box remotely.

The desktop app sits and waits for a command to be sent to it.  I have tried using "shutdown -h" but this requires sudo privileges and is not an option.  I then found a way to shutdown without sudo using the following dbus-send solution:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown
```

This works fine but I am trying to figure out, using dbus-send, if its possible to do a timed shutdown similar to "shutdown 3600" which would shut the computer down in 1 hour?

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HAL, which function you are calling, does not provide this feature. But you can always go with something like this, if you are launching an external command anyway:

```
sh -c "sleep 1h; dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown"
```