# Remotely shutdown/restart a Linux machine without password

Tags: linux, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, dbus

I am writing a pyQt client-server application which restarts/shutdowns PCs remotely.
The **receivers** are listening to the network for incomming messages, and the **sender** sends a restart/shutdown message to the selected receiver.

The following part of code is running on a receiver:

```
import os

self.currentOS = calling a function to determine the current OS

if self.currentOS == "Win":
    os.system("shutdown -r -f -t 1")
elif self.currentOS == "Lin":
    os.system("shutdown -r now")
```

I have 2 virtual machines acting as receivers, one on Windows and the other on Linux.

When i send a restart message to the Windows receiver, the machine restarts.
When i send a restart message to the *Linux* receiver, *it asks for password*

```
Incoming:EXEC_OP_RESTART
[sudo] password for jwalker:
```

What do i have to change to overcome this?
Is `shutdown -r now` the only way, or can i do this another way (more directly)?

EDIT:
In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696644/linux-shutdown-with-dbus-send) question, something called `dbus` was used, and it was done without a password, i am searching about dbus, as an alternative.

Comment: For reference, both Linux and Windows can use `shutdown -r -t 1`.  On Windows, `-t 1` implies `-f`, so you don't have to specify that option (which means something totally different on Linux).

Comment: @cHao incorrect . `-f` in Windows imply **forced shutdown**. does not equal to `-t 1`. See: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shutdown.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @Shivan: I'm looking at `shutdown -?` right now.  It explicitly says for /t, "If the timeout period [`-t`] is greater than 0, the /f parameter is implied."  It *also* says for /f, "The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is specified for the /t parameter."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It takes root privileges to restart a Linux machine. Some desktop environments use a daemon to get around this.... but I suggest editing the sudoers file

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers for a howto. Basically you'll want to allow the restart command - and only the restart command - to be run without a password.

Something like:

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/shutdown
```

will let any user on the machine restart it without using a password. You'll probably need to prefix the 'shutdown' in your system command with 'sudo', though it looks like it's being called automatically somehow. If this isn't secure enough, you can make a group, make your program run as that group, then allow that group to restart.

EDIT: Apparently this can be done with DBus (note: I haven't tested this):

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.Hal" /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Restart int32:0
```

This works because dbus runs as root (or has root privs) and can therefore accept requests to restart from nonpriveleged processes and act on them. I still think the sudo way is cleaner, and so will anyone who maintains this code.

Comment: Thank you Robert. About the use of a password, editing sudoers looks promising. Also, i just found out about something called `dbus` (see edit), that someone used to do the same without even using a password.

Comment: That's the daemon I mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge in Linux is very limited. Is there a library to include in my program, or must i install something on the target machine? I am asking because i get an error when i try to execute the dbus-send command.

Comment: Both of these methods shouldn't require any additional work. Both are simply executing a particular command. The sudo method is more likely to be portable, and definitely more straightforward, while the dbus method works if you don't have root priveleges (to edit the sudoers file).

Answer (score 1):

Run the script with `sudo python`. For example, if your file were named remotesd.py, `sudo python remotesd.py`

Comment: Insecure, particularly for a network listener. At least if he can get away without broad root privs, he should.

Comment: Better would be to run the specific `shutdown` command with `sudo(8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Other than `sudoers` file change which gives the user extra (sometimes unwanted) privilege on the machine, you may use `setuid`.
i.e. Change the owner of the executable to root by calling `sudo chown root:<caller's username> thefile`  Then change the permission of the file to 4750.  This way whoever has the permission to execute the file will be considered as root on execution.